# WAMP server not allowing a php search engine?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I'm trying to create a search engine that will pull out information from a mySQL database. My code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Search Engine Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script language="php">
// Create a database connection

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if (!connection) {
    die("Please reload page. Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

// Select a databse to use
$db_select = mysql_select_db("test", $connection);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Please reload page. Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

// Search Engine
// Only execute when button is pressed
if (isset($_POST['keyword'])) {
    // Filter
    $keyword = trim($_POST['keyword']);

    // Select statement
    $search = "SELECT Price FROM 'table_1' WHERE * LIKE '%$keyword%'";
    // Display
    $result = mysql_query($search) or die('query did not work');

    while ($result_arr = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $result_arr['*'];
        echo " ";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
    }

    $anymatches = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($anymatches == 0) {
        echo "Nothing was found that matched your query.<br><br>";
    }
}
</script>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="keyword">
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
```

However, when I run it, I receive a notification saying that I've been forbidden to access the server. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you paste the error here?

Comment: could be a httpd.conf issue.

Comment: `wwhile` should have been `while`. I have fixed it assuming it was just a typo.

Comment: Does that query work when connected to MySQL directly (via phpmyadmin or MySQL Workbench)? I haven't seen WHERE * before and can't see it in any documentation (you need to specify a field name.)

Comment: `SELECT Price FROM 'table_1' WHERE * LIKE '%$keyword%'== >>  SELECT Price FROM 'table_1' WHERE name LIKE '%$keyword%'`

Answer (score 0):

`$search = "SELECT Price FROM table_1 WHERE fieldname LIKE '%$keyword%'";`

You can't use single quotes around a field name, as that's how strings are defined. You can use the grave key (`) if your table name is a reserved word. You also can't do WHERE *, you need to specify a field to compare the keyword to.

I would also recommend not using the mysql commands in PHP as they are deprecated. Use the more recent [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) commands